# How to preserve user uploaded file in git?

Tags: git, web, repository, openshift

I am having a application in openshift in which there is a option by which a user can upload an image. All the images uploaded by users is stored in location "/images/" All the thing is going well.

BUT when I modify/add file in my local Git Repository,

$ git commit -a -m "Modify local repo" 
$ git push

After pushing, all the file uploaded by user get deleted.

I though it was due to the file uploaded by user is not in the local repository when i commit and push git delete the files for the very same reason.

I tried $ git pull before commit and push but it say Already up-to-date.

How can i preserve the user uploaded files or how to syn it to local repository.

In simple word How can I get the copy of missing file in local repository from remote without cloning if i have only one local repository??

Comment: Do you have a `.gitignore` that might be affecting this process?

Comment: ya in my local repository \.openshift\cron directory contain daily hourly minutely monthly and weekly all the directory except weekly contain a file named .gitignore which is blank  (0 byte).

Answer (score 0):

OpenShift has a useful [knowledge base article about persistent storage](https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202398490-Persistant-storage-for-OpenShift-applications), which says:

> When you deploy new versions of your application, the OpenShift service will replace your application tree with a fresh copy of your git repository. The result of this is that any files that were created by your application will be deleted if they are stored in git controlled directories.

The solution is listed on the same page:

> The best practice for storing files that must persist across deployments is to use the 'data' directory that is located one level up from your git repository. You can use the `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` env variable to reference this on the host.

Comment: it is not possible for me to change the location of directory because i can't change path of images in hundreds of pages.
Is there any way by which i can sync my local repository with remote before commiting?

Comment: @Azad, the correct solution is the one I've outlined in my answer. Even if you do manage to update your local copy, *user-uploaded images shouldn't be committed to your codebase*. They are *content*, and therefore fundamentally different from your source code.

Comment: @Azad, you may be able to fix most of your image paths using cross-file find-and-replace. If you do that, it's probably worthwhile to use a variable instead of a hardcoded path, so if you ever want or need to move your images again it becomes as easy as changing a variable.